# How to set Focus back onto form input in delphi?

Tags: delphi

Delphi 10seatle Pro

i have 2 forms : mainform and subform .

the mainform contains mainmenu and pageControl (named = mainpageControl) .

the subForm  contains 2 Tedit .

the subForm created dynamicaly from the mainmenu as the following :

- first create tabsheet (newTabSheet) and set it is pagecontrol to  mainpageControl.
- then create panel and set it parent to newtabsheet.
- finally create the subform and set it is parent to the created Panel.

  ```
  var
   newTabSheet : TRzTabSheet;
   frm : tform;
   pnl : TPanel;
  begin
    newTabSheet := TRzTabSheet.Create(pgcPreview);
    newTabSheet.Caption     := 'New Tab';
    newTabSheet.PageControl := mainpageControl;
    pnl          := TPanel.Create(tbsheet);
    pnl.Align    := alClient;
    pnl.Parent   := newTabSheet;
    frm          := TFrmSubform.Create(pnl);
    frm.parent   := pnl;
    frm.Align    := alClient;
    frm.BorderStyle := bsNone;
    frm.Visible := true;
    mainpageControl.ActivePage := newTabSheet
  end
  ```

this code work perfectly and each time i click on the mainmenu Item, a new tabsheet created that contains instance of the form.

OnKeyUp of the TEdit i clear all the text and setfocus to first edit but the focus go to the mainmenu.
 **so how to setfocus back to the edit on the form?**

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] showing exactly what you are doing

Comment: Use frames, forms are not meant to be parented.

Comment: Just a tip, but if you're going to parent either forms or frames, then in your code example, there's no need for the intermediary TPanel.  Just set frm.parent := newTabSheet.

Comment: @Stuart i do that to control the position of controls on the form,because when i set the bidimode to bdRightToLeft  all my controls disappeared from the form.

Comment: Note that SetFocus cannot be use directly. You need to call firs CanFocus. But even that will not work in all cases. CanFocus is  **BROKEN**  (or incomplete in Delphi). Please check this article on how to [fix it](https://gabrielmoraru.com/setfocus-is-broken-in-delphi/)